# Optical distance measurement idea

Tags: measurement, distance, optical

Ok, so I posted this using my phone some time ago, more than a year ago.  However let's just take it from the top, integrating the criticisms that I remember.

I am a cnc machinist by trade and we could really use a good, cheap method of measuring distances like this.

My idea works like this:

1. A cylindrical rod is lathed to make a conical indentation in the end.
2. a ball bearing (ball) goes in the indentation.  This makes sure the ball bearing is very precisely aligned with the center of the rod.
3. Now comes the hard part.  A laser diode with say a 30 degree emission angle is used, with no optics between it and the ball bearing.  It emits light, the ball bearing reflects it, and a very very small fraction of the light hits the laser diode after reflection.
4. Now there are two problems.  One, it is a very very small amount of energy that returns, however radios use techniques to discern signal strengths in the trillionth of a watt range.  Many techniques could be employed here to get the signal into a reasonable signal to noise range and measure it.
5. ok, now we are going to measure the distance along the optical path using the speed of light, however it is not time of flight as you know it, and it does not depend on brightness.  It it not like any of the other methods that you are probably thinking of.

This is the hard part.  The returning light signal has to modulate the output of the laser.  This creates a feedback loop.  If done carefully with the details right, oscillations will arise in the amplitude of the light emitted by the laser diode, and the period of these oscillations will be very very close to the total signal propagation time.  This includes the time it takes for the signal to propagate through any electronics.

Now, we simply measure the frequency of the oscillations using a phase locked loop that is referenced to a calibrated can oscillator.

The key here is that accuracy is imported in the accuracy of the oscillator, which are available calibrated to like 20 parts per billion, with built in temperature and supply voltage compensation etc. and they are only a couple bucks.  The main key here is to import that accuracy and use the speed of light combined with a low cost reflector and emitter and low cost electronics to get something practical.

Now, the absolute path length will not be quite right, i.e. it will not be exactly equal to the distance from the center of the laser diode to the center of the ball bearing, because there will be bias.  There are several other things which I can think of which introduce issues, but I think generally speaking small *changes* in distance should be detectable very repeatedly and reliably as very small changes in frequency, which can be detected with phase locked loops and related techniques very reliably. The temperature of the electronics would have an impact probably, response times of components will change etc.  I get it, but this is just the general concept at this stage.  I think it's a pretty good start.

Ok, so that is the core of the concept, but the reason it's interesting is partly because you can have 3 of them shining on the same ball bearing.  Then you can make some assumptions and triangulate the center of the ball bearing with tremendous precision and even accuracy.

This would be extremely useful for calibrating CNC machines.  You would have a thick rigid metal plate, room temperature, with the emitters on it, all shining in the right area.  Then you mount the reflector in the collet of e.g. a milling machine, and move the machine around and build a compensation table.  It would be great.  Existing methods are expensive and very laborious, I can tell you.

I appreciate that there are many complications, such as the possibility of harmonic oscillations arising and so on, which would complicate things and increase cost, but at the end of the day it is way simpler and cheaper than interferometric techniques, for instance.

Any legit major flaws you can spot?

Edit: light falling on a laser diode or led changes it's electrical characteristics, but it might be hard to pluck that signal out of other variations.  Maybe a semi silvered beam splitter and separate detector would be a good idea, these things are commonly used in those checkout counter type laser scanners.  They can pick up the reflected light from a label no problem but that's probably a lot more light yeah.

Comment: Obviously a key consideration will be how exactly the returning light beam modulates the laser.  I don’t have an answer to that.  Another consideration is that the laser may modulate at a harmonic of the time of flight, although this could be addressed using some other method to get an approximate distance.  It’s also worth checking how much the speed of light in air varies with atmospheric conditions; probably not much but I’d imagine enough to add measurably to 20ppb.

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/nphoton.2006.11
That’s perhaps the kind of technology you’d need, but using the small amount of reflected light would be problematic, as you’ve mentioned.  A large lens or reflector might help, but of course the more you put into the loop the more the errors will accumulate.

Comment: BTW if the total distance measurement error is even 2 parts per million that's plenty. that's 2 microns over a meter!

Comment: Keysight and others already make [interferometric machine tool calibration systems](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/products/laser-interferometers-calibration-systems/laser-calibration-systems.html).

Comment: It's been almost 5 years btw: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/398860/optical-path-resonance-distance-measurement-device-super-useful-for-open-source

Comment: Again, this is not interferometry. My previous post isn't that bad, actually, I just galloped ahead with the details a little prematurely.  However that's also how you get things done.  I wrote all that on a crummy phone too.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you're describing something close to low coherence interferometry, which is used in manufacturing and machining for non-contact distance measurement.

It's actually much easier than you're thinking too. You don't need good temperature control or an electronic oscillator with high accuracy because you can turn the problem from absolute measurement to relative measurement with a beam splitter or a fiber coupler and fiber of known length. You heterodyne the reflected signal with the signal that passed through a known length, the difference in frequencies is subtracted, and now you only need to measure some kilohertz or megahertz signal, and a 1% frequency error only results in a 1% length error. This makes it very simple calibrate and gives very high absolute accuracy.

If you're interested there are commercial products available. You can also build your own for maybe a few thousand dollars, depending on how cheaply you can find the optics on eBay. Usually though contact probes are good enough for this sort of thing.

Comment: Hm, I was thinking like a hundred bucks or so for the equipment.  This method of using a known length is a good idea, and could be used to calibrate the device in the factory for sure.  

I have searched for commercial products, and as with many of my ideas would be over the moon to see someone already doing it so I could just buy it use it and move on to the next thing :).    However I  have not been able to find any examples of exactly this kind of thing, mechanism, cost and performance.

Comment: @user7311634 I've met with a few vendors over the years when they had engineering questions, typically given the very high cost relative to contact measurement probes the applications were in very high end precision manufacturing or machining tools in applications where contact wasn't allowed. For example, one was interested in scanning parts of turbine engines. The issue with niche optical components is that prices are very high for small production runs, so you're either paying more $100 just for a single lens or scavenging on eBay.

Comment: If you want very low cost, consider using a confocal ranging system. Essentially a lens with a pin hole or optical fiber behind it in the back focal plane. When a reflective object enters the front focal plane it will focus light through the lens into the pinhole or fiber. Otherwise no light gets through. A cheap plastic lens can easily get down to a few microns depth of focus, and from there you can fit the surface location to nanometers. Then you move the lens or the object to scan for distance (so limited by motor accuracy). Very simple though.